# Is there a Duke Nukem Forever playable demo?

Tags: duke-nukem-forever

Does anybody know it a playable demo was released?

Comment: I hear that Microsoft employees have had access to the full game for a while.

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE:** Duke Nukem Forever demo is now available to all directly from its [Steam game page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/57900/).

Duke Nukem Forever demo has been first released to people that pre-ordered the game or people that bought Borderlands 'Game Of The Year Edition' or any version of Borderlands on Steam.

If you had an Early Access Code you could retrieve the code for demo activation on Steam here: http://www.dukenukemforever.com/access/

Comment: I don't see a demo on the page!?